# Focus Windows processor on one process

Tags: windows

Is it possible to let one Windows processor only compute one specific process? I run a Python script that is not parallelized and I want to force the computer to treat it as a priority.

I couldn't find something on this in the internet, but that could also be due to the fact that I don't really know what to search for...

Comment: You can set the affinity of a process to a specific processor but if you want the computer to treat it it with priority, just change the priority of the process.

Comment: Thank You, @LievenKeersmaekers, that sounds like the thing I'm looking for - How can I do that?

Comment: This is a prime example of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Alright, thanks for that amusing but true hint! So, I actually know how to parallelize the program, I just wondered if there was a brute-force way :)
But yeah so I accepted the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, depends on the processor but you can look for your individual processor.

I also would not try it as most processors automatically assign as much processing power as needed to a task.

Of course all depends on your processor